# Why can't I add word in a trie via pygtrie?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, data-structures, trie

I want to build a trie to record the phrases. Thus the unit is word instead of character. And I have found a promising implementation by google [here](https://github.com/google/pygtrie). But according to their [documentation](http://pygtrie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#), there is no `add` function. I wonder how can I add/insert a word into a trie? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This trie implementation provides the same interface as a dict.  Your `add` function would simply be `mytrie[key] = value`.